# Move endDrawer above bottomNavigationBar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, drawer, bottom-navigation-bar

We have a `endDrawer` that is displaying **behind** the `bottomNavigationBar`. We want it to display `over` the navigation bar.

We may need a refactor but for now, we have a main Scaffold like so:

```
return Scaffold(
      key: shellKey,
      drawer: const MainDrawer(),
      body: child,
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: const ExpandingBottomDrawer(),
);
```

The `router` pushes the `child` to this Scaffold via

```
ShellRoute(builder: (context, state, child) => AppLayout(child: child),...)
```

The `children` are also `Scaffolds` that have independent `endDrawers`. In the children, I am triggering opening the endDrawer via `_key.currentState!.openEndDrawer(),`.
The issue is the `endDrawer` is visibly behind the `bottomNavigationBar`. I understand this can be fixed if the `endDrawer` was on the main Scaffold, but the app is not set up that way and it would be a huge refactor. Is this possible without a refactor?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use another Scaffold widget.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  drawer: const Drawer(),
  bottomNavigationBar: Container(
    child: Text("Bottom navBar"),
  ),
  body: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    drawer: const Drawer(),
  ),
);
```

There might be  a better way of handling this.